# Php Dynamic Dropbox

Tags: php, html, sql

I created the following code,which enables the dropdown to get all the values from sql db, its able to get the number but not displaying ..

```
    <?php
$link = mysql_connect('www.xxxxxxxx.com', 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", $link);

function print_dropdown($query)
{
$queried = mysql_query($query);
$menu = '<select name="Topic">';
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($queried)) {
$menu .= '
<option value="' . $result['topic'] .'</option>';
}
$menu .= '</select>';
return $menu;
}


echo print_dropdown("SELECT topic FROM learning_outcome");
?>
```

But the output seems to be empty .. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$menu .= '<option value="' . $result['topic'] .'</option>';
```

should be like:

```
$topic = htmlspecialchars($result['topic']);
$menu .= '<option value="' . $topic .'">' . $topic . '</option>';
```

Comment: was about to post the same :)

Comment: Thanks this fixed it. one more question if i want to sent the selected value to another php page to process, i should send  $menu right ??

Comment: @Tina How do you send `$menu`, you just need to use `$_POST['Topic']` to get the selected value.